# Chrome extension keeps resetting

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm new to chrome extension development but I'm running into issues debugging and with the extension itself. I currently have a form with a submit button and after the user hits submit I change the html to show the data that was just submitted.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  console.log("1");
  document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener('click', myFunction);
  console.log("2");
  //getCurrentTabUrl(function(url) {
  // renderStatus(url);
  //});
});

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML = document.getElementById("formInput").value;
  alert("hi");
  console.log("test");

);
}
```

In this, 1 and 2 are displayed to the extension debugging console and the alert runs as well when the button is clicked. The test shows up very briefly and then it disappears.The formoutput value changes very briefly as well and then changes back to the default value I have. Does anyone know why my code/the chrome extension would be doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When button with type `submit` (This is the default if the attribute is not specified) is clicked, the form data will be sent to server and page will be redirected to new page. Then your content script will be injected again, that's why the it changes back to default value.

To avoid this, you could change button with [other types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), or calling `e.preventDefault` to prevent default behavior. Then you would want to use [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) to send data to server, which ensure the whole page won't be redirected and only parts of UI can be updated.

Comment: Switched it over to a button instead, that worked. Thank you!